Writing a SQL Query with multiple Where statements
Can someone offer some guidance on how best to write a query that has multiple where statements.
This query will look at our current students and exclude those in year 13 who will be definitely leaving us, exclude the students who have notified us that they are leaving from other year groups but will need to include students that we have been told are joining us.  This will mean I can run the report now to get a list of students who will be here at the start of the new school year in September.
I have 2 tables that I am pulling data from.
The first is dbo.TblPupilManagementPupils and the columns I am using are:

txtSchoolID (unique student identifier)
txtSurname
txtForename
intNCYear (student year group)
txtAcademicHouse (student house)
txtForm (student tutor/form group)
intSystemStatus (-1 means student has left, 0 mean they haven't started yet and 1 means they are current)
intEnrolmentSchoolYear (the year the student will join the College e.g 2024)
txtEnrolmentTerm (which school term the student will join eg Winter, Spring, Summer)
txtAdmissionsStatus (identifies whether they are definitely going to join us.  This would be "6. Accepted")
txtLeavingDate (is a datetime column showing an exact leaving date)

The second is dbo.TblPupilManagentCustomFieldValue and the columns I am using are:

txtSchoolID (unique student identifier)
txtValue (lists a number of custom data fields per student.  This would filter to the value "Definite Leaver")

The following query returns all of the students who are here now and will be staying in September:
SELECT ppl.txtSurname, ppl.txtForename, ppl.intNCYear, ppl.txtAcademicHouse, ppl.txtForm
FROM TblPupilManagementPupils AS PPL
WHERE ppl.intSystemStatus = '1' AND ppl.intNCYear < 13 
ORDER BY ppl.txtSurname, ppl.txtForename

The following query returns all of the students who are currently at the school but have notified us that they are leaving:
SELECT        PPL.txtSurname, PPL.txtForename, PPL.txtLeavingDate, TblPupilManagementCustomFieldValue.txtValue AS LeavingType
FROM            TblPupilManagementPupils AS PPL LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         TblPupilManagementCustomFieldValue ON PPL.txtSchoolID = TblPupilManagementCustomFieldValue.txtSchoolId
WHERE        (TblPupilManagementCustomFieldValue.txtValue = 'Definite Leaver') AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), PPL.txtLeavingDate, 126) LIKE '2024-08-31%')

The following query returns all of the students who will be joining us at the start of the next school year:
SELECT ppl.txtSurname, ppl.txtforename, ppl.intEnrolmentSchoolYear, ppl.txtEnrolmentTerm, ppl.txtAdmissionsStatus
FROM dbo.TblPupilManagementPupils AS ppl
WHERE ppl.intsystemstatus = 0 AND ppl.intEnrolmentSchoolYear = '2024' AND ppl.txtAdmissionsStatus = '6. Accepted' AND ppl.txtEnrolmentTerm = 'Michaelmas'

I have tried a few different ways of combining these queries and none have worked.  If anyone can give me some pointers on how to write this query I would be grateful.
I have tried coalesce select sub queries and writing my query in different ways but cannot get an accurate list.  I know the exact number of students as I have calculated this manually.

Just use WHERE (NOT) EXISTS and put your queries in correct sequence

What do you want your output to look like?

I would suggest UNION or UNION ALL, but the three queries are returning different numbers of columns.

Could it be this?
select PPL.txtsurname
    , PPL.txtforename
    , PPL.intncyear
    , PPL.txtacademichouse
    , PPL.txtform
from TblPupilManagementPupils as PPL
    --left join only pupils who will be leaving
    left join TblPupilManagementCustomFieldValue L on L.txtschoolid = PPL.txtschoolid
                                                  and L.txtvalue = 'Definite Leaver'
                                                  and cast(PPL.txtleavingdate as date) = '20240831'
where L.txtschoolid is null --exclude everyone who got left joined
    and ( --keep pupils only if they are below year 13
        (PPL.intsystemstatus = '1' and PPL.intncyear < 13)
        or --OR they join next semester
        (PPL.intsystemstatus = 0
        and PPL.intenrolmentschoolyear = '2024'
        and PPL.txtadmissionsstatus = '6. Accepted'
        and PPL.txtenrolmentterm = 'Michaelmas')
    )
order by PPL.txtsurname, PPL.txtforename


Thanks so much for this.  Looks like this has done the trick although I have just spotted something else.  The students who are joining have their intncyear in another column called intEnrolmentNCYear, their txtacademichouse in another column called txtEnrolmentAcademicHouse and their txtform in txtEnrolmentForm.  When The students are enrolled through the web interface this is copied into the other fields.  I think there is a way of saying if intncyear is null then use intEnrolmentNCYear.  Is this right?

Yeah, that would be coalesce(intncyear, intEnrolmentNCYear) (the first non-null value will be used from left to right). Or something like iif(intsystemstatus = 1, intncyear, intEnrolmentNCYear) if you require more logic. iif is a Microsoft shorthand for the case statement, which one could also use.

The UNION operator is used to combine the results of the three individual queries.
In this combined query:
-- Query to retrieve students who are currently at the school and will be staying in September
SELECT txtSurname, txtForename, intNCYear, txtAcademicHouse, txtForm
FROM dbo.TblPupilManagementPupils
WHERE intSystemStatus = 1 AND intNCYear < 13

UNION

-- Query to retrieve students who have notified that they are leaving
SELECT PPL.txtSurname, PPL.txtForename, PPL.txtLeavingDate, CFV.txtValue AS LeavingType
FROM dbo.TblPupilManagementPupils AS PPL
LEFT JOIN dbo.TblPupilManagementCustomFieldValue AS CFV ON PPL.txtSchoolID = CFV.txtSchoolId
WHERE CFV.txtValue = 'Definite Leaver' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), PPL.txtLeavingDate, 126) LIKE '2024-08-31%'

UNION

-- Query to retrieve students who will be joining in the next school year
SELECT txtSurname, txtForename, intEnrolmentSchoolYear, txtEnrolmentTerm, txtAdmissionsStatus
FROM dbo.TblPupilManagementPupils
WHERE intSystemStatus = 0 AND intEnrolmentSchoolYear = 2024 AND txtAdmissionsStatus = '6. Accepted' AND txtEnrolmentTerm = 'Michaelmas'


Thanks for this but I received the following error:  All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Yes , all 3 queries should have a same columns names
